# Attribute [JsonProperty] for rename property of DTO class in C#

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

[UPDATE 1]:
Add My Controller and Application Layer Class

My Controller:

```
  [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<FormulaItemsDTO>> Create(Create.Command command)
        {
            return await _mediator.Send(command);
        }
```

My Create Class in Application Layer

```
 public class Create
    {
        public class Command : IRequest<FormulaItemsDTO>
        {

            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public List<FormulaInput> FormulaInputs { get; set; }
          
        }
        public class Handler : IRequestHandler<Command, FormulaItemsDTO>
        {
            private readonly PlantimsDbContext _context;
            public Handler(PlantimsDbContext context)
            {
                _context = context;
            }
            public async Task<FormulaItemsDTO> Handle(Command request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {

                using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    try
                    {

                        foreach (var item in request.FormulaInputs)
                        {
                            FormulaInput formulaInput = new FormulaInput();
                            formulaInput.FormulaId = item.FormulaId;
                            formulaInput.TagId = item.TagId;
                            formulaInput.Position = item.Position;
                            _context.FormulaInputs.Add(formulaInput);
                        }

                      
                        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                        transaction.Commit();

                        return null;
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        transaction.Rollback();
                        throw new Exception("problem saving change");
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

I have a DTO class and I want to map that class to a JSON request. I added JsonProperty from Newtonsoft to my DTO class but doesn't work. After sending the request through Postman, FormulaInputs is null when callign the EndPoint in the Contoller.

```
public class FormulaItemsDTO
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "formula_inputs")
        public List<FormulaInput> FormulaInputs{ get; set; }
    
    }
```

JSON file:

```
{
  "formula_inputs": [
    {
      "key": "tagP051001FI0071PV",
      "tag_id": "P051001FI0071PV",
      "position": "B3",
      "column": "B"
    },
    {
      "key": "tagP051001FI0076PV",
      "tag_id": "P051001FI0076PV",
      "position": "C3",
      "column": "C"
    },
    {
      "key": "tagP051001FI0077PV",
      "tag_id": "P051001FI0077PV",
      "position": "D3",
      "column": "D"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share the sample json ?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I added the sample json file

Comment: Just to be sure: did you set up your app to use Newtonsoft? Because from .NET Core 3+ it will default to use `System.Text.Json`.

Comment: I think this is related to `IRequest<FormulaItemsDTO>`, an alternative method that will accept `FormulaItemsDTO` instead of Command, and add the `[FromBody]` property, then you will be able to successfully receive the FormulaInputs data, and then you can assign FormulaInputs field in FormulaItemsDTO to the FormulaInputs field in the Command.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have explicitly switched to use Newtonsoft.Json as your JSON serializer, the default with ASP.NET Core 3 is to use the new JSON serializer `System.Text.Json` built into .NET Core, which has a smaller feature set but more focus on performance.

In that case, you cannot use the JSON attributes that come with Newtonsoft.Json but you will have to use the attributes that are in the `System.Text.Json` namespaces. In your particular case, you will have to use the [`[JsonPropertyName]` attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute?view=netcore-3.1):

```
public class FormulaItemsDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("formula_inputs")
    public List<FormulaInput> FormulaInputs { get; set; }
}
```

You can read more about the differences between Newtonsoft.Json and System.Text.Json [in the documenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to). If you want to switch back to the Newtonsoft.Json serializer, which is a thing that you might need to do if you have to rely on more advanced features, then you can follow the [migration guide to 3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#newtonsoftjson-jsonnet-support) and simply switch back.

Comment: Then you will need to provide additional information about what exactly you are doing. You could for example test if the `Id` property gets filled or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `underscore` from your Json array name `"formula_inputs"`. Then request data would be mapped to `FormulaInputs` collection inside your DTO class `FormulaItemsDTO`.

And no need to use `JsonProperty` attribute.

**Update**

If it is required to not chnage the Json formatting, as in this case array name is having `underscore`. Then add naming strategy in your `Startup.cs` inside `ConfigureServices`

```
services.AddControllers()
.AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver { NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy() };
});
```

Comment: Yes.I know.
but I want to konw is any solution without rename the  Json array name

Comment: Are you doing this inside your application or sending this Json as a request body to call an API?

Comment: yes I sending this Json as a request body through Postman to call an API